# CKEditor templates window do not pop up

Tags: templates, ckeditor

I implemented CKEditor on website. Everything is working fine but when I click on templates icon - windows with templates do not pop up. Other popup windows like Pictures works fine.

I tried simple page with CKeditor on local desktop and it works fine.

Can it be something with setting of the server?

Error from console:

```
Uncaught Error: [CKEDITOR.dialog.openDialog] Dialog "templates" failed when loading definition.
CKEDITOR.tools.extend.openDialog @ ckeditor.js:2107
(anonymous function) @ ckeditor.js:2107
f @ ckeditor.js:760
z @ ckeditor.js:761
A @ ckeditor.js:761
CKEDITOR.env.ie.CKEDITOR.env.version.f.$.onerror @ ckeditor.js:765
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project have some redirect rule in .htaccess for url which contains word 'temlates'. Thx to my co-worker for solution